# Spring Cloud Dataflow custom stream application metrics aren't showing up in Grafana

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

SCDF version 2.10.2

I can't get my custom source, processor or sink to expose metrics to my prometheus/grafana setup.

---

I've followed the custom stream application tutorial here: https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/streams/standalone-stream-sample/

I've found various sources on what dependencies I need to add to my applications to get them to track in my grafana/prometheus setup but nothing seems to work. If I use the sample applications from dataflow.spring.io in my streams then I get metrics flowing to grafana.

At a minimum it appears I need this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-starters-micrometer-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

That doesn't seem to do anything.

I've seen some other stackoverflow answers suggest adding these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer.prometheus</groupId>
    <artifactId>prometheus-rsocket-spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Those don't seem to work either and result in a NoClassDefFound: io.rsocket.AbstractRSocket exception.

Full pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.10</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ca.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>data-poller</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.23</version>
    <name>data-poller</name>
    <description>Poller for data</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.6</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <classifier>test-binder</classifier>
            <type>test-jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-starters-micrometer-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>prometheus-rsocket-spring</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>





    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dataflow-apps-metadata-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <storeFilteredMetadata>true</storeFilteredMetadata>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>aggregate-metadata</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate-metadata</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The samples https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/main/monitoring-samples/stream-apps show the dependencies. They versions are a bit outdated.

You need to deploy the prometheus-rsocket-proxy to ensure the metrics are published before the task shuts down.

Adding the following properties may help for short lived tasks:

```
management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.base-url=http://prometheus-rsocket-proxy-host:7001
management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.shutdown-operation=PUSH
```

These dependencies should do the job along with boot version 2.7.11.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer.prometheus</groupId>
    <artifactId>prometheus-rsocket-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```